# Use Arduino to turn fan on / off

Tags: esp8266, nodemcu

I have a simple fan.
When I plug it to GND and Vin it spins.
I'd like to have the ability to turn it on / off with code.
Any example will do, as long as it gets it to spin.
I have a NodeMCU board, if that helps.

Comment: Use a MOSFET as digital switch. Fan+ to Vin, Fan- to MOSFET drain, MOSFET source to ground, MOSFET gate to a digital pin of the Arduino. You can google MOSFET as a switch

Comment: Related if not dupe: https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/54018/17196 and https://arduino.stackexchange.com/q/54145/17196

Comment: google images "mosfet switch low side"

Answer (score 2):

Depending of the type of fan you are using, two solutions exist.

- First one, use a MOSFET to drive the FAN from you nodemcu
- Second one, use a relay to drive the FAN from your nodemcu

Things to consider :

- The mosfet allow you to drive the fan without mechanical part moving.
- The relay require some transistor and feedback diode to be driven by your µc.

Comment: What about a motor driver?

Comment: Motor driver in the end is just several mosfets connected in a smart way. It's unnecessarly complicated and redundant if fan just spins when you supply power. There is a very good chance that the fan already has a driver inside it (all computer fans do)

Answer (score 0):

So I didn't have a transistor to do a MOSFET, but I did have a motor driver which I ended up using. From there it was just finding example code to use the motor driver, connecting it up and using it.